# Error while calling createBuyOrder(): API Error 400: ['Expected exchange contract address to match']

Tags: opensea

I keep receiving

> API Error 400: ['Expected exchange contract address to match']

when executing the code below:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const opensea = require('opensea-js')
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: "myPhrase",
    providerOrUrl: "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/myID",
    addressIndex: 0
});
console.log("test1")

const seaport = new opensea.OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: opensea.Network.Rinkeby,  // Main network:opensea.Network.Main
  //apiKey: No API key used
})
console.log("test2")
const call = async () => {
    const accountAddress = "0xcB189FD4D7C924fC4b607B7f05c02989Be9F1aE4"
    const tokenId = 12
    const tokenAddress = "0x0e9076fbeb063ead63b9eeb84b41694a8bbf8ddb" //https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x0e9076fbeb063ead63b9eeb84b41694a8bbf8ddb/12
    console.log("test3")
    const offer = await seaport.createBuyOrder({
      asset: {
        tokenId: tokenId,
        tokenAddress: tokenAddress,
        schemaName:"ERC721"
        
      },
      accountAddress: accountAddress,
      startAmount: 0.005,
      paymentTokenAddress:'0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab'
    })
    console.log("success")
  }
 
  call().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

My truffle-config.js looks like this

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const mnemonic = "myPhrase";
module.exports = {
 networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/myID")
      },
      network_id: 4
    }
  }
}
```

Some things to add

1. I have enough wETH on my metamask account to conduct this transaction (i.e. 0.1 rinkeby wETH)
2. When executing the same code, i also get the "request timed out" error very often. the following errorcode shows that there are some issues with truffle (or anything reporting to truffle)
3. I am very new to this. Thus there is the potential that I missed something rather basic

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating opensea.js to the latest version solved the issue